# How can I verify the length of text of a cell after sending keys?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a field I am populating with text and trying to ensure that only the first 9 characters are pasted since there there is a restriction on how many characters should be able to be pasted to the field.

I am sending the keys as:

```
cusipField.sendKeys("1234567890") ;
```

The command to get text I believe would only work after saving.  This is what I was hoping I could use :

```
cusipField.getText() ;
```

Is there way to get the text out of an editable field?

Answer (score 1):

If your 'field' is an input, its text is hiding in the value attribute which you can get as :

```
element.getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: @user3061041 You should accept the answer if it worked for you.